# file uploading using <s:file> in Struts2

Tags: struts2

I am working on struts2 application. I have following in my jsp (say main.jsp) –

```
<s:file name="sampleDocument"/>
<s:submit action="uploadSample" value="Upload" />
```

See here how my struts.xml handling the action -

```
<action name=" uploadSample " class=" UploadFiles">                 
        <result name="success"> /main.jsp</result>
        <result name="input"> /error.jsp</result>
</action>
```

Its all running well. As required file is uploading. But as you have seen I am calling same jsp page (i.e main.jsp) on SUCCESS. Its coming but `<s:file>` textbox in empty. I mean its there is no file name that I have browse before uploading. Can anyone know how to get this?

Answer (score 0):

You need properties on your action that reflect the names of the parameters in your JSP. Have a look at [this documentation](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.11.1/docs/file-upload-interceptor.html) for an explanation of which properties to look for.

Comment: Same I have done but after uploading file when same jsp page appears it does not show the name of the file browsed, i.e textbox of <s:file> tag comes empty. Suggest.

Comment: Do you have the value attribute of the tag set?

Answer (score 0):

you should define getter and setter functions for fileName. This will ensure that the value is populated in the view once it returns from the action.

Answer (score 0):

The value of the `<input type="file"/>` element is cleared by default for security reasons.

See [How to set a value to a file input in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696877/how-to-set-a-value-to-a-file-input-in-html)